# Cannot assign to a read only property

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a form which has a `TDBLookupComboBox` on it.

The `TDBLookupComboBox` is displaying a list of records from within a database table.

At the point of the forms `OnShow` event I would like the `TDBLookupComboBox` to already display one of the strings in the list.

I have done this so far...

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dblucbox.Text := Username;
end
```

Username is a string for one of the records already in the list.

At the point of compiling, I get an error saying

> Cannot assign to a read only property

I'm a bit stuck with this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that `dblucbox.Text` is read only. Presumably `dblucbox` is of type `TDBLookupComboBox`? The documentation confirms what the compiler is telling you: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TCustomDBLookupComboBox.Text

Comment: You can't change a Lookup field, you need to change the fields that are being looked up.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to modify the [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TCustomDBLookupComboBox.Text) property, instead if you want set the [`TDbLookUpComboBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBLookupComboBox) in a particular item you must use the the [`KeyValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TCustomDBLookupComboBox.KeyValue) property which will try to locate the record in the underlying TDataSet.

So you if you have Key Value of the user you can use something like this

```
 dblucbox.KeyValue := UserId;
```

Otherwise you can use the Locate method of the underlying TDataSet, to find the match and the LookUp control will be refreshed automatically

Comment: More likely you want `dblucbox.KeyValue := UserId;`

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this backwards. To be more precise, the DBLookupCombo is reflecting the state of the database table. So you want to be manipulating the table, not the combobox.

In other words, the OnShow event needs to open the table that's the object of the DBLookupCombo (if it's not already open) and then position the current record to be the one you want displayed as the default.